# Eclipse 'Loading data for Android 4.4.2' all the time

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Kepler SP2 with the latest ADT plugin. Every other minute Eclipse is saying 'Loading data for Android 4.4.2' and blocks everything I want to do. I have several instances of Eclipse in different folders (only running one at a time) and it happens with all of them. 
This is driving me nuts. Anything I can do about it?

Comment: It also happens to me (Eclipse ADT Bundle -> Juno), after upgrading to the latest SDKs (and checking for updates). But only when saving and launching. And loading.

Comment: I have also updated both ADT and Android SDK to version 23 but the problem still persists. Its very frustating !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I updated to latest version, `ADT 22.6.2`. Work like a charm.

It seems they fixed that in that version.

Comment: Yep, everything running smooth now!

Comment: my eclispe is the version with adt bundle in android developer site link. Also updated to ADT 22.6.2. but still issue there.when open a xml layout always loading data.

Answer (score 3):

Just change this value from your layout menu to :

> > > Android version to use when rendering layout in Eclipse : 19 to 18 or 17

Comment: #Himani - Any specific reason for doing that...? that information would be helpful instead of just blindly following....

Comment: yes because each SDK is slightly larger than the previous one (each having more APIs and more resources) so it would make sense for newer SDKs to take more time to load.

Answer (score 0):

Close all projects in your workspace (make sure you do it for all working sets if you have more than one). Then open only those projects that you are actually working on.

Comment: That's a good tip but I only have the projects in my workspace that I need (my project and referenced library projects).

Comment: Then it could be your system resources. Try defragmenting the disk which holds the SDK.

Answer (score -1):

I have been having the same problem with all the latest softwares installed. I tried opening XML files with XML Editor instead of the default Android Common XML Editor. Then, 'loading data' disappears.

- This is not the optimal solution, but in the short term, it saves you from the "loading data for android ..." hang, and eclipse runs fine.
- The disadvantage is that you won't have the benefits, like auto-complete, that Android XML editor provides.