# How to load a specific SDK?

Tags: android, eclipse

When I start **Eclipse** this last take a long time to load SDK  W.W, X.X, Y.Y, Z.Z ..

So there are a way to load only one SDK (X.X by example) ?

[image]

**EDIT**

*JAVA BUILD PATH WINDOW*
[image]

*PROJECT STRUCTURE*

[image]

Comment: before closing eclipse i close all my projects first, so that next time only plain eclipse is started and then i open my project individually which is required so that only the required Android SDK is loaded. This happens mainly when you have more that one SDK project in same work space.

Comment: @harshal all my projects are closed but when i restart eclipse, all the sdk loaded

Comment: I think thats because many of the widgets and all that stuff are introduced in each android versions..ie all of the features are not included in each and every android versions.. for example buttons may be introduced in android 1.1 ..so it need not be again specified in android 2.1 and so on..So inorder for the buttons to work in android 4.4 data for android 1.1 also should be fetched..

Comment: @Lal i'm not sure because i don t have sdk 1.1 installed and i work with buttons

Comment: I just said 1.1 as an example..

Comment: i have eclipse  3.7.1, with SDK API 19,18, 14, 10. what i suggested solved me. i f i leave my projects open then i too face same issue as you

Comment: @harshal i lets only one project open but when i restart eclipse all sdk's are loaded

Comment: i would suggest to share screenshots of project structure and build path config window... some one might get an idea.

Comment: @harshal get look to my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have this issue as well. Let's go through possible fix steps as one of them should solve it.

1. Ensure all of your projects are targeting the same API if possible.
2. Update ADT to the newest version (this was an issue before `22.6.2`, see [Eclipse 'Loading data for Android 4.4.2' all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631577/eclipse-loading-data-for-android-4-4-2-all-the-time))
3. In the Layout Menu, find "Android version to use when rendering layout in Eclipse" and set it to 18 or 17 (19 might be causing the issue).
4. Last ditch: create a new workspace and reload everything you need. I did this once when I was pulling my hair out before I tried anything else and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**The three most influential factors for boosting Eclipse speed are:**

1- using the latest version of Eclipse

2- Launching it with the latest JDK

3- configuring the eclipse.ini [(see this question for a complete eclipse.ini)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse#144349)

-Xms128m
-Xmx384m
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-Xss2m
[...]